# Are the dexed libs extracted during installation? If so, where?

Tags: android, android-library

I have an Android project which has few other Android library projects.
When I build the Android project, I see a folder called `dexedLibs` inside which there's a `jar` file (with only META_INF & classes.dex) for each of my library projects.

My question is, when I install my actual project in the device, are the jar files (my library projects) extracted to some location? If so where? And how can I access that jar file from my project (as a File itself).?